# C++ weighted graph using classes, dynamic array allocation

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I'm learning C++ and trying to understand more about classes. Currently I'm trying to create a weighted graph and was successful in prototyping it using the following code:

```
class Edge{
    int nextVertex // vertex the edge goes to in a directed graph
    int itsWeight
public:
    Edge(int v, int wt) // constructor
    int getWeight()
    int getVertex()
};

void addEdge(std::list<Edge> adj[], int vertex1, int vertex2, int weight)
void printGraph(std::list<Edge> adj[], int numOfVertices)

int main()
{ std::List<Edge> adj[5];
    // add some edges then print
}
```

I'm certain this can be better implemented using pointers, but I'm taking things one step at a time. I tried to modify this into a Graph class and it runs, but not for what I want.

```
class Edge;

class Graph
{
    int numberOfVertices = 1;
    std::list<Edge> adj[5];         <- Problem

public:
    Graph(int V) { numberOfVertices = V; }
    void addEdge(int u, int v, int wt)
    std::list<Edge> getEdges(int u) { return adj[u]; }
    void printGraph()
};

int main()
{ Graph G(5); 
    // add some edges and print
}
```

So what I don't understand is how I would allocate the size of the array for a particular graph, since I won't know what size it will be until it gets passed in via the constructor.

I believe there's some way to do this using 'new' and 'delete', but someone talking me through that would be beneficial.

Comment: You can find *graph.h* and *graph.cpp* files for an implementation with no pointers here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/249314/k-clustering-algorithm-using-kruskal-mst-with-disjoint-set-in-place-to-check-for

Comment: You are using `std::List` which should be typed `std::list` to be picky, but in any case it does not need to be initialised as you would do with an array, you can remove the bracketed `[5]` and expand the `list` with new elements dynamically.